# how to remove search box from Vista start menu?

Tags: windows-vista, start-menu

Is it possible to remove the search box from the Windows Vista Start Menu?

Comment: Why would you want to.  That's one of the few good things Vista has going for it.

Answer (score 1):

You gotta edit the registry:

1. Run Regedit and open to
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer or
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer
2. Create a new DWORD value, or modify the existing value, called "NoFind"
3. Change/Set the value to 0 for disabled.

You'll most likely have to reboot for it to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove the search box.

Comment: well, i just killed it in a fresh windows 7 installation, when i activated the advanced settings in Ccleaner ... search box gone :)

Comment: @Molly was that on purpose?