# "Run" textbox in Windows 7 gone

Tags: windows-7, run-dialog

Since Vista, there's been a text box you get when you click the start button, in which you type to filter on programs.

I've found that it's gone here. Disabled or whatnot, I don't know. How can I get this back?

Comment: Minor comment: That sounds like **search** rather than **run**.  [picture of RUN on win7 x64](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6s8zQ.png).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to `Programs and Features` in `Control Panel`. Click on `Turn Windows Features on or off`, go at the lower part, check if `Windows Search` is unchecked. If it is, check it then press OK.

Answer (score 3):

Even if the run box is disabled you can still bring it up by pressing the win+r key combination

Comment: No, that one doesn't show possible matches.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [similar question posted](https://superuser.com/questions/54093/how-to-remove-search-box-from-vista-start-menu), except asking how to remove it.  You may want to follow the instructions to see if the search box is disabled.